# Visualize multiple timelines

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-visualization

I collected a data set that comprises the terms of office for different politicians of a country. There are the terms of the national leader and the terms of around thirty provinces. An entry has the name of the leader, the province he or she was ruling and the start and end of tenure. My goal is to visualize these terms. This is my imagination of how it should look like in the end:[image: Visualization of leaders]

I would like to visualize this data set by using python3 and pandas. My first approach started with abusing [Plotly - Gantt charts](https://plot.ly/python/gantt/#group-tasks-together). I like about this component, that on hoover a title can be shown, which is useful for short tenures. Furthermore, I can group the leaders and there is a nice timeline at the x-axis. I also like the feature of zooming in and out and all other dynamic features.

The *Plotly Gantt Chart* requires a data set with the following columns:`Task`, `Start`, `Finish`, `Resource`

I use `Task` to group the leaders by provinces or as national leaders. `Resource` is used to add a color and a label to the box of a leader.

But there I some flaws, that make the component not perfectly match my needs:

1. I would like to get rid of the tool-tips, that are shown when hoovering over the end or start of a box.
2. Whenever a color in a `Resource` is used more than once for a leader, all labels receive the same name of only one leader.

For the first problem I think I could [modify the figure after the figure factory returns it](https://plot.ly/python/gantt/#group-tasks-together). And thereby deactivate the undesired tool-tips. But I am not sure how to achieve this.

For my second issue I have to take care, that all colors have to be different in at least one of the three RGB values. This would lead to nearly 500 different colors, what I do not prefer, but it would be a valid option. Perhaps somebody knows how to modify the figure, that was returned from plotly's figure factory and thereby follow a better approach.

**Important:**
This question focuses heavily on the Plotly Gantt Charts. Perhaps somebody knows a better solution for displaying multiple timelines as shown above in my makeshift diagram.